# Error: cannot create document: File not in PDF format or corrupted, while converting base64 string to pdf using react-native-pdf

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, pdf

I am trying to convert a base64 string to pdf using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf

I am using "react-native": "0.64.0", Here is my try,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Button,Image,View,Platform,Alert,StyleSheet,Dimensions,Text,} from 'react-native';
import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';

export default function ImagePickerCamera() {
  const source = {
    uri:
      'data:application/pdf;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..............4R//Z',
    cache: true, // tried with cache: false, not works
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>test</Text>
      <Pdf
        source={source}
        onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
          console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
        }}
        onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
          console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
        }}
        onError={error => {
          console.log(error);
        }}
        onPressLink={uri => {
          console.log(`Link presse: ${uri}`);
        }}
        style={styles.pdf}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  pdf: {
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});
```

I read some article for this issues, this is a specific problem to react native for android,

https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/issues/174

I did not find a solution, I tried few suggestions, it did not work for me.
Can anybody know, how to solve this issue for react native android,

Comment: Are you sure that your url is valid?

Comment: I think so, it is a valid URL, I am converting an image to a base64 string using

https://www.base64-image.de/

It works fine if I use a pdf URI, I am trying using a base64 string

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `'` with `"` in URL, like this:

```
const source = {uri:"data:application/pdf;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..............4R//Z"};
```

Just for reference here are some examples from [docs](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf):

```
 const source = {uri:'http://samples.leanpub.com/thereactnativebook-sample.pdf',cache:true};

 const source = require('./test.pdf');  // ios only
 const source = {uri:'bundle-assets://test.pdf'};

 const source = {uri:'file:///sdcard/test.pdf'};
 const source = {uri:"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKJc..."};
```

Comment: I tried with " ", does not works it also.

Comment: Try removing `cache` completely

Comment: Are you sure it will work no not? Why are you telling randomly something?

Comment: I didn't try it; I'm just telling you what would I do. If I had that problem. If nothing of this thing hasn't worked, it most certainly means that problem is not in shown code.